# Internal & External Links

Tags: c#

Fetch `href's` and other sort of tags which can have URL's embedded. In short get all the `URL's`from a given web link. There are many ways of fetching `URL's` i.e. Regular Expressions, HtmlAgilityPack, Dcsoup etc... I wanna know which one is best?

Comment: HTML can't be parsed using regular expressions. Use an HTML Parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Not sure if "can't" is the right word Panagiotis, but I would agree with "shouldn't".     Much better options available, such as the one you suggested

Comment: Regex *can* be used to parse HTML, but it's rather like trying to put a nail in a wall using a sledgehammer

Answer (score 1):

Regarding HtmlAgilityPack, here's sample code from their examples:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
{
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
}
doc.Save("file.htm");
```

It grabs all `<a>` elements that have `href` attribute. This example loads document from file, but there is of course possibility to load document from string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for parsing HTML documents.  You would also need to use XPath to easily parse HTML.

Regex can also be used but using XPath is much more suited for this job.

Comment: The problem with XPath is that, HTML document may not be formatted well. That is one of requirements of XPath.

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx